# Making a switching news feed for a web page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, asp.net

For a project i'm working on the users that are logged in with enough priveledge to post a new news item are able to see a button to add news items. I would like to show these news item with 'switching styles' (for the lack of a better word). I'm pulling the data from a database where the user submits it through a form on a seperate page. Then i'm requesting all of the news items back on the home page where it lists them as a 'news feed'. The feed fetches like a charm and can be seen here : http://prntscr.com/et39yp

I would like to make the second, fourth, sixth, etc have the first-image or first-video list on the left, like so : http://prntscr.com/et3akw

Is there an easy way of doing this?

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Default");
    var fetchRows = "SELECT * FROM Articles";
    db.Execute(fetchRows);
    var articles = db.Query("SELECT articleTitle, articleText, articleVideoUrl, articleImage FROM Articles ORDER BY id DESC");
    var articleTitle = db.Query("SELECT articleTitle FROM Articles");
    string lorem = "";
}

<div class="Articles">
    <h2>Nieuws Feed</h2>
    @foreach (var title in articles)
    {
        <div class="article">
            @{
                string text = title.articleText;
                string firstLetters = new string(text.Take(50).ToArray());
                <div class="col s6">
                    <h3>@title.articleTitle</h3>
                    <p>@firstLetters</p>
                    <a href="~/LeesMeer.cshtml?title=@title.articleTitle">Lees meer...</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col s6">
                    @{
                        if (title.articleVideoUrl != lorem)
                        {
                            //Iframe for youtube feed here
                        }
                        else if (title.articleVideoUrl == lorem && title.articleImage != "")
                        {
                            <div class="result">
                                <img src="@title.articleImage" alt="image"/>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Now the switching news article thing is something i would be able to work out, the thing i'm struggling with would be the following. The user is able to edit / remove news items. So i cant keep track of an index value or anything similar since it would be invalid should the user remove an item from the middle of the feed. My first guess would be to use the .toggleclass of javascript and that would probably work with originially loading the items but if the user would remove an item it wouldn't show them the right way after. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS nth child selectors to see if that works? alternatively, tried some javascript to reapply styles when the news items are re-ordered?

Comment: Nth child sees every item as the first since they are all being fetched seperatly.

Comment: Did you get this working Marco, if the answer worked remember to mark it as accepted, if you came up with your own solution add it and accept it when you can so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter that you are adding the items individually, the `nth-child(odd|even)` should still work.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chairman_Mau/uap93rtL/4/ - notice when you click the move up/move down buttons the style changes automatically.

**HTML**

```
<div class="articles">
    <h1>header</h1>
    <div class="article">
        paragraph
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        paragraph
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        paragraph
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        paragraph
    </div>
    <div class="article movethis">
        paragraph - move this one
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        paragraph
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="add article" class="addarticle"/>
     <input type="button" value="move up" class="moveup"/>
      <input type="button" value="move down" class="movedown"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".addarticle").click(function () {
  $(".articles").append('<div class="article">added</div>');
});

$(".moveup").click(function(){
      var prev = $(".movethis").prev('.article');
    $(".movethis").detach().insertBefore(prev);
});

$(".movedown").click(function(){
        var next = $(".movethis").next('.article');
    $(".movethis").detach().insertAfter(next);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.articles .article:nth-of-type(even)
{
    color: Green;
}
.articles .article:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    color: Red;
}
```